# IE9 defineGetter Error Terraformer.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-9

I have an MVC4 application I am working on and each time I try and run it in IE9 I get an error saying:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method '**defineGetter**' 
terraformer.js, line 1007 character 5

this is the line of code getting the error:

```
  this.__defineGetter__("bbox", function(){
  return calculateBounds(this);
  });
  }
```

i am trying to create a new incident from a properties dialog box but it will not let me continue. it works fine in crome. i dont know why it keeps going to this terraformer.js file too. i am really new to all this coding so any help or advice will be greatly appreciated. someone told me i can try to update the terraformer file but im not sure how to do that. i really hope someone can help me move forward with this issue.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just needed to update the terraformer code from github with an updated version. doing this fixed the problem and now i get no errors.